# Make a scrollview scroll underneath another widget in kivy

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, kivy

I want to overlay a rectangle, button, and label on top of a scrollview gridlayout in kivy, to provide a banner with the name of the current screen and a button to the nav popup. I've made a gridlayout list of buttons to link to future minigames in a puzzles app.

The contents I want to put on top are inside screenmanager.kv, and the gridlayout is in gameslist.kv.

Everything displays to the screen. The gridlayout scrolls vertically. However, it scrolls *over* the contents of screenmanager.kv, not under it. I want the banner to stay visible, floating over the grid, persistently in the same place at the top of the window, despite where the user has scrolled in the gridlayout.

screenmanager.kv:

```
<GamesListScreen>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 0.6, 0.6, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.width, (self.height * 0.15)
            pos: 0, (self.height * 0.85)
    Button:
        color: 1, 1, 1, 0
        size_hint: None, None
        height: Window.height * 0.15
        width: self.height
        pos: 0, (root.top * 0.85)
        on_release:
            root.open_NavPopup()
            print('pressed')
        Image:
            source: 'images/NavIcon.png'
            keep_ratio: False
            allow_stretch: True
            y: self.parent.y
            x: self.parent.x
            size: self.parent.size

    Label:
        font_size: self.width * 0.1
        color: 1,1,1,1
        center_x: self.width / 2
        y: self.height / 2.35
        text: 'Games List'
```

gameslist.kv:

```
#:import ScrollEffect kivy.effects.scroll.ScrollEffect
#:import Button kivy.uix.button.Button

<RootWidget>
    effect_cls: ScrollEffect
    GridLayout:
        do_scroll_x: False
        height: self.minimum_height
        size_hint: 1, None
        size: Window.width, (Window.height * .85)
        spacing: 5, 5
        padding: [0,(Window.height * .17),0,0]
        cols: 1
        on_parent:
            self.add_widget(Button(text = "Game 1", size_hint_y = None, height = Window.height * .1))
            self.add_widget(Button(text = "Game 2", size_hint_y = None, height = Window.height * .1))
            self.add_widget(Button(text = "Game 3", size_hint_y = None, height = Window.height * .1))
            self.add_widget(Button(text = "Game 4", size_hint_y = None, height = Window.height * .1))
            self.add_widget(Button(text = "Game 5", size_hint_y = None, height = Window.height * .1))
            self.add_widget(Button(text = "Game 6", size_hint_y = None, height = Window.height * .1))
            self.add_widget(Button(text = "Game 7", size_hint_y = None, height = Window.height * .1))
            self.add_widget(Button(text = "Game 8", size_hint_y = None, height = Window.height * .1))
            self.add_widget(Button(text = "Game 9", size_hint_y = None, height = Window.height * .1))
            self.add_widget(Button(text = "Game 10", size_hint_y = None, height = Window.height * .1))
```

gameslist.py, just in case:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
Builder.load_file('gameslist.kv')

class RootWidget(ScrollView):
    pass

class runGamesList(App):
    def build(self):
        root = RootWidget()
        return root
```

I tried changing the canvas.before to canvas.after and putting the overlay inside of the gridlayout so it scrolls with it. Neither worked. Any tips? Or should I give up and do something that scrolls on the x-axis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please refer the example and output for details.

## gameslist.py

1. Add *from screenmanager import GamesListScreen*
2. Change the root widget from *ScrollView* to a *BoxLayout*.

## gameslist.kv

1. Add *#:include screenmanager.kv*
2. Declare GamesListScreen as a child widget of the RootWidget
3. Make changes to the ScrollView

## Example

### gameslist.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from screenmanager import GamesListScreen


class RootWidget(BoxLayout):
    pass


class GamesListApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    GamesListApp().run()
```

### gameslist.kv

```
#:import ScrollEffect kivy.effects.scroll.ScrollEffect
#:import Button kivy.uix.button.Button
#:import Window kivy.core.window.Window
#:include screenmanager.kv

<RootWidget>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    GamesListScreen:

    ScrollView:
        effect_cls: ScrollEffect
        size_hint: 1, None
        size: Window.width, (Window.height * .85)

        GridLayout:
            do_scroll_x: False
            height: self.minimum_height
            size_hint_y: None
            spacing: 5, 5
            cols: 1
            on_parent:
                for i in range(10): txt = "Game {}".format(i); self.add_widget(Button(text = txt, size_hint_y = None,
                height = Window.height * .1))
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - App Startup]
[image: Img02 - Scroll]
[image: Img03 - Navigation Button clicked]